# How to find amount of similarity between two GPS co-ordinates in android

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to make a database of locations/Adresses for corresponding GPS co-ordinates for my city. And I will be using that data base for reverse geocoding instead of geocoder class of android(as it gives wrong reults sometimes or don't give any results). But the problem I am facing is, whenever I try to use data base by comparing my current GPS co-ordinates with stored for fetching address, the current GPS co-ordinates don't match with stored. It is because there is only a small change(2-3 digits difference) between current and stored GPS co-ordinates as I am moving. So is there any way(algorithm) to check amount of similarity between co-ordinates using which the current co-ordinates will get matched(nearly equal) with stored ones and then I can get address?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate the distance between the current GPS coordinates and the stored ones, and use this distance as the measure of similarity between the locations. You could consider two locations identical if they are within some predefined distance from each other.

The only problem is that using a brute force approach you'll have to calculate the distance from the GPS coordinates and every stored point. If that works for you, then you're good. Otherwise you'll have to optimize the process somehow. One of the possible approaches is to use a square grid and for each square store the locations that are within this square. Then you take your GPS location, determine which square it falls into, and then compare it only with the locations in the same and adjacent squares on the grid.

Comment: Thank you. Actually implementing haversine formula on android seems difficult to me. I will use the second approach of grid squares. So for it I will have to make a database in android, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think just the grid squares alone will do the trick - you'll have to calculate the distances to the candidate locations anyway. It's not that hard, you can easily google up the implementation, and it most definitely involves the math functions that are available to an Android developer.
And yes, you'll have to implement some kind of a database - which you would have to do anyway.